# How is `join` implemented in Maybe/List monad?

Tags: haskell, monads

`join` can be defined implemented in terms of `>>=`:

```
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
join m = m >>= id
```

Specifically, how is it implemented in a Maybe and a List monad?

Is it in Maybe monad:

```
join Nothing = Nothing
join (Just (Just x)) = Just x
```

and in List monad:

```
join [] = []
join [[xs]] = [xs]
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: Exactly the sam way, with `m >>= id`.

Answer (score 5):

`join` is implemented *exactly once*, and it works for all types that are Monads.

The very point of the Monad abstraction is to enable working on different types in the same way. Once you provide `>>=` (and `return`) for your type, and make sure they follow the Monad laws, any code that is generic enough to only use those operations will work on your type correctly.

Answer (score 4):

`join` is just a regular function, implemented in terms of the preexisting `(>>=)` function. You don't have to worry about *which* monad is used; `(>>=)` takes care of that.

Conversely, `Monad` *could* have been defined in a way closer to its mathematical definition:

```
class Monad' m where
    return :: a -> m a
    join :: m (m a) -> m a
```

with

```
(>>=) :: Monad' m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
x >>= f = join (fmap f x)
```

as the regular function. Then the list-specific definition of `join` would just be `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]`:

```
instance Monad' [] where
    return x = [x]
    join = concat
```

Comment: [BTW](https://ryanglscott.github.io/2018/03/04/how-quantifiedconstraints-can-let-us-put-join-back-in-monad/).

Answer (score 3):

`join` is just [implemented as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#join):

> ```
> join              :: (Monad m) => m (m a) -> m a
> join x            =  x >>= id
> ```

If we take a look at the monad instances of [`[]` [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-984) and [`Maybe` [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-854), we see:

> ```
> instance Monad []  where
>     {-# INLINE (>>=) #-}
>     xs >>= f             = [y | x <- xs, y <- f x]
>     {-# INLINE (>>) #-}
>     (>>) = (*>)
>     {-# INLINE fail #-}
>     fail _               = []
> ```

> ```
> instance  Monad Maybe  where
>     (Just x) >>= k      = k x
>     Nothing  >>= _      = Nothing
>
>     (>>) = (*>)
>
>     fail _              = Nothing
> ```

So that means that for lists, `join` is equivalent to:

```
-- for lists
   join xs
-> xs >>= id
-> [ y | x <- xs, y <- id x ]
-> concatMap id xs
-> concat xs
```

so for lists, the equivalent implementation is:

```
join_list :: [[a]] -> [a]
join_list = concat
```

For `Maybe` we can do case-analysis: the input is a `Maybe (Maybe a)` so there are basically three possibilities here:

```
-- (1)
   join Nothing
-> Nothing >>= id
-> Nothing

-- (2)
   join (Just Nothing)
-> Just Nothing >>= id
-> id Nothing
-> Nothing

-- (3)
   join (Just (Just x))
-> Just (Just x) >>= id
-> id (Just x)
-> Just x
```

So that means that for `Maybe`s the equivalent implementation is:

```
join_maybe :: Maybe (Maybe a) -> Maybe a
join_maybe (Just x) = x
join_maybe Nothing = Nothing
```

`join` is thus not *reimplemented* for list or `Maybe` monads, it simply uses the implementation for `(>>=)` for lists and `Maybe`s, and since these differ, the behavior of `join` is of course different.

Comment: @join: well it is not implemented per monad instance. The definition is each time the same. It is the ad-hoc polymorphism of `(>>)` that here ensures the behaviour is different.

Comment: [someone was *wrong* on the internets](https://xkcd.com/386/). all's better now. :)

Comment: @WillNess: and the best way to get a correct answer, is giving a wrong answer, not asking a question :)

Comment: id has type of id :: a -> a, how can it be used in x >>= id ?  (>>=) requires a type of (a -> m b), doesn't it ?

Comment: @user1461328: `id` has type `a -> a`, so it can for example take as specific type `Maybe Int -> Maybe Int`, and thus then it can typecheck when using it with `>>=`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: `Maybe Int -> Maybe Int`  is still basically`a -> a`, not  `a -> m a`.  Could you please explain how this is applied to `Nothing `, like `join Nothing` ?

Comment: @user1461328: it is, note that it is `a -> m b`, and thus `id :: c -> c` (note that the variables are different ones, so we better do not use `a` twice) can unfiy with `a ~ Maybe Int`, `m ~ Maybe` and `b ~ Int`.

Comment: @user1461328: it is key that it is a `b` in `a -> m b`, that thus means that `a` can be monadic, and `m b` as well.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, thanks a lot for answering my stupid questions. I think I got your point now.